# How to list all the processes assigned to a user on a cluster

Tags: bash, ssh, grep, slurm

We have a cluster in our university controlled by SLURM. The issue is that I have observed sometimes some of the resources are not being realised even though they do not show up in the `squeue` command. For example I have seen that a lot of CPUs on one of the nodes are assigned to me despite the fact that I had killed the allocated resources with `scancel` a couple of days ago! I want to find them and kill them.

On my local machine I have generated public and private ssh keys with `ssh-keygen` so now I can login to any of those machines with `ssh foo`, `ssh user1@bar.uni.com`, `ssh user1@baz.uni.com` ... but the names of those nodes are not in an order. If one login to one of those nodes and run `sinfo` this is the result:

```
PARTITION   AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
debug          up   infinite      3    mix baz[080-081,083]
debug          up   infinite      2  alloc grault,baz082
debug          up   infinite     13   idle baz[061-070],corge,bar,quux
gpu_p100       up   infinite      1    mix baz080
gpu_titan-x    up   infinite      2    mix baz[081,083]
gpu_titan-x    up   infinite      1  alloc baz082
r730           up   infinite      1    mix baz080
t630           up   infinite      2    mix baz[081,083]
t630           up   infinite      1  alloc baz082
r930           up   infinite      1  alloc grault
m610           up   infinite     10   idle baz[061-070]
r720           up   infinite      1   idle corge
r815           up   infinite      1   idle bar
sm1u           up   infinite      1   idle quux
main*          up   infinite      3    mix baz[080-081,083]
main*          up   infinite      2  alloc grault,baz082
main*          up   infinite     12   idle baz[061-070],bar,quux
```

where `baz[081-083]` is referring to 3 nodes `baz081`, `baz082` and `baz083`.
no if I ssh into any of these nodes I can list all the processes assigned to a specific user by:

```
ps -A | grep user1
```

but that would take a lot of time. How can I automate this process:

1. login to one of the nodes
2. run `sinfo`
3. extract the information and make a list of strings from the last column of `sinfo` command
4. find all the running processes with a specific user `user1` and prints to the terminal

How can I write an script, preferably compatible with Cmder/ConEmu, to automate these steps.

Answer (score 3):

This will try to login to all nodes and print processes of user1:

```
    for hostList in $(sinfo -h | awk '{print $6}' | sort -u); do
            for host in $(scontrol show hostname $hostList); do
                    echo $host; ssh $host "ps aux | grep user1";
            done;
    done;
```

However, as you probably do not want to login to offline nodes, extend the sinfo command to:

```
        for hostList in $(sinfo -h | grep -v down | awk '{print $6}' | sort -u); do
```

There might be even better ways to accomplish this with better knowledge of sinfo / scontrol but this script should do the job.

However, if this happens a lot you might consider, talking to your administrators as orphaned processes are bad for the cluster performance in general. They should ideally be cleaned by the system automatically on a regular basis.

Comment: thanks a lot. I'm trying to go through the code step by step. The first issue is that to get the `sinfo` you need to first ssh into one of the servers, lets say `foo`

Comment: You can put the code in a file "checkAllServers.sh" in your home on the server and run it from your machine via
       `ssh foo bash checkAllServers.h`

or you can run the whole code in one line via:
`ssh foo 'for hostList in $(sinfo -h | awk '{print $6}' | sort -u); do for host in $(scontrol show hostname $hostList); do echo $host; ssh $host "ps aux | grep user1"; done; done;'`

Comment: If i want to run the bash on one of the nodes then I have to put my private key there, which can be read by everyone else. What I want is to run the script from my own computer(s). Is there any way to pip the output of a command ran on the server to the local machine?

Comment: Ok, I think if we replace `sinfo -h` with `ssh foo "sinfo -h;"` the problem is mostly solve the only issue is that the `-u` flag for sort doesn't work and leads to the `The system cannot find the file specified.` error.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Noco's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/466983/167505) and further investigation I wrote the perfect script for my own purpose:

```
#!/bin/bash 
hostList=$(ssh foo "sinfo -h" | awk '{print $6}' | sed 's/,/\n/g' | awk '!seen[$0]++' | sed '/\[/d')
for host in $hostList; do
    echo $host;
    ssh "$1@$host.uni.com" "ps aux | grep $2";
    #ssh "$1@$host.uni.com" "pkill -f $2";
done;
```

where `foo` is the main node in my case. This script accept two arguments as `sh script arg1 arg2` where arg1 is the `user1` as indicated in OP and `arg2` is the keyword it will search for. If one wants to remove all the processes assigned to that key word , he/she should uncomment the line with `pkill` command.

What I observed is that the nodes showing as `baz[080-081,083]` are all the same in may case so need to search all.